# Regex to filter non-minified files

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regex to filter non-minified JavaScript files from an array.

Currently, the following expression works:

```
array_filter($paths, function($path) {
    return preg_match('@\.js$@', $path) && !preg_match('@\.min\.js$@', $path);
});
```

However, I wanted to write this as a single regular expression:

```
preg_grep('SOME_REGEX_HERE', $paths);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookbehind:

```
preg_match('@(?<!\.min)\.js$@', $path);
```

Here `(?<!\.min)` is negative lookbehind that makes sure `.js` is matched only when it is not preceded by `.min`